# How do I guarantee that the request happened correctly when mocking an API?

Tags: go, testing

Let's say I'm testing a feature that calls a web service, and that service is mocked with `httptest.NewServer`

```golang
func TestSomeFeature(t *testing.T) {
    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(200)
    }))

    SomeFeature(server.URL, "foo")
}

func SomeFeature(host, a string) {
    if a == "foo" {
        http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("%v/foo", host))
    }
    if a == "bar" {
        http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("%v/bar", host))
    }
}
```

How do I assert that the server was called with the right url `/foo` and fail the test if it was called with the wrong url or not called at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
func TestSomeFeature(t *testing.T) {
    called := false
    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // assert that strings.Contains(r.RequestURI, "/foo") is true
        called = true
        w.WriteHeader(200)
    }))

    SomeFeature(server.URL, "foo")
    // assert that called is true
}
```

Comment: Are there no concurrency issues if I run several of these in parallel with the same `server`?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen of course the above code is for sequential testing, you didn't specify concurrency in your question