# How to assert that the request happened when mocking an API concurrently?

Tags: go, testing

Followup question to: [How do I guarantee that the request happened correctly when mocking an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70087909/how-do-i-guarantee-that-the-request-happened-correctly-when-mocking-an-api)

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func SomeFeature(host, a string) {
    if a == "foo" {
        resp, err := http.Get(host + "/foo")
    }
    if a == "bar" {
        resp, err := http.Get(host + "/baz"))
    }

    // baz is missing, the test should error!
}
```

`main_test.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestSomeFeature(t *testing.T) {

    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(200)
    }))

    testCases := []struct {
        name     string
        variable string
    }{
        {
            name:     "test 1",
            variable: "foo",
        },
        {
            name:     "test 2",
            variable: "bar",
        },
        {
            name:     "test 3",
            variable: "baz",
        },
    }
    for _, tc := range testCases {
        tc := tc
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            t.Parallel()
            SomeFeature(server.URL, tc.variable)

            // assert that the http call happened somehow?
        })
    }
}
```

- GO Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/EFanSSzgnbk
- How to do I assert that each test case send a request to the mocked server?
- How can I assert that a request wasn't sent?

All while keeping the tests parallel/concurrent?

Comment: You got and accepted an answer to this the last time it was asked, minus the concurrency piece. Your example code doesn't use any method described in that answer, and you ask the same questions again about checking if the call was made. Can you clarify what your question is and what you're still missing after taking into account the answer to the previous question?

Comment: The previous question doesn't handle concurrency, so I'm looking for a way to handle that. As far as I know using a variable like in the previous answer will cause a race condition, so I wanted to know how it's supposed to be done? I've seen it done with mux and channels, but I'm wondering what the proper way is.

Comment: Then show your implementation that handles checking, and people can help you ensure it works concurrently. In the example in your question, nothing is doing those checks, so it's impossible to help change how they're done.

Comment: @Adrian How would I do that if I don't know how to do that? To give an example of that check, I'd have to implement this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70102527/175071 which would defeat the purpose of the question or am I wrong?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would defeat the purpose. Your question seems to be "how do I do this thing concurrently", which is much easier to answer if your example code is doing the thing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new server for each test case.

---

Or you can use channels, specifically a map of channels where the key is the test case's identifier, e.g.

```golang
getChans := map[string]chan struct{}{}
server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    key := strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")[1] // extract channel key from path
    go func() { getChans[key] <- struct{}{} }()

    w.WriteHeader(200)
}))
```

Add a channel key field to the test case. This will be added to the host's URL and the handler will then extract the key, as demonstrated above, to get the correct channel. Also add a field to indicate whether `http.Get` should be called or not:

```golang
testCases := []struct {
    name      string
    chkey     string
    variable  string
    shouldGet bool
}{
    {
        name:      "test 1",
        chkey:     "key1"
        variable:  "foo",
        shouldGet: true,
    },
    // ...
}
```

Before running the test case add the test-case-specific channel to the map:

```golang
getChans[tc.chkey] = make(chan struct{})
```

Then use the channel key field in the test case as part of the host's URL path:

```golang
err := SomeFeature(server.URL+"/"+tc.chkey, tc.variable)
if err != nil {
    t.Error("SomeFeature should not error")
}
```

And to check whether or not `http.Get` was called use `select` with some acceptable timeout:

```golang
select {
case <-getChans[tc.chkey]:
    if !tc.shouldGet {
        t.Error(tc.name + " get called")
    }
case <-time.Tick(3 * time.Second):
    if tc.shouldGet {
        t.Error(tc.name + " get not called")
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/7By3ArkbI_o

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you think of a solution without involving a timeout?

Comment: @PaimanRoointan off the top of my head no, not if you opt to use channels. You could however use a mutex with a map of bools that tracks which test cases triggered a GET request, something like this: https://go.dev/play/p/e2Ttk0WmtNr